# Fetch content from an API though JSON gives wrong data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to fetch a number from this API:

https://api.bithumb.com/public/ticker/btc

I'm trying to get the `sell_price`.

My fetch function works ok, because I was able to get the data from another API very well, it was well organized in arrays.

I have this function :

```
var price_USD = document.getElementById('price-btc-usd-humb');
var USDPrice = data.data.sell_price;
price_USD.innerHTML = USDPrice;
```

or the same with

```
var USDPrice = data.data.sell_price[0];
```

both only give me the first figure of the whole number in both case.

Do you know what can be my mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following snippet. It gets the `sell_price` using `fetch()`:

```js
fetch('https://api.bithumb.com/public/ticker/btc')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    var price_USD = document.getElementById('price-btc-usd-humb');
    // notice USDPrice here is a string
    var USDPrice = json.data.sell_price;
    price_USD.innerHTML = USDPrice;
        
    // you can convert it to int
    var USDPriceNumber = parseInt(USDPrice);
    console.log(USDPriceNumber);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

```html
Price: <span id="price-btc-usd-humb"></span>.
```

Comment: Sorry for letting you comment all this code, I could have pasted mine, it is exactly the same. Also I don't use json.data, this option is not recognized by my browser. I need to write data.data because the "data" is redondant in the json from the API. But only gives me the first figure of the whole number.

Comment: If it is exactly the same, what is the problem you face, exactly? What did you want to get but isn't?

Comment: I use `json.data` because it is declared here: `.then(function(json) {`. If this was `.then(function(data) {`, then the correct would have been `data.data`.

Comment: the response is "2" instead of "21000000". Oh sorry didn't get that :p

Comment: Did you run my code? In it the response is not `2`, it is `21122000`. If you still get `2` in it then it would be really weird :D

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what the problem is. When you run my code (the blue button, `"Run code Snippet"`), are you seeing, on the space that appears, the number `21046000` (or similar)? Or are you seeing `2` only?

Comment: Ok got it now, it may be because of a version error in my ftp or in my cache ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with:

`var USDPrice = data.data.sell_price[0];`

because the API returns:

`{
  status: "0000",
  data: {
    opening_price: "21308000",
    closing_price: "21140000",
    min_price: "20132000",
    max_price: "21970000",
    average_price: "21168606.8824",
    units_traded: "32077.49761093",
    volume_1day: "32077.49761093",
    volume_7day: "262188.14880950",
    buy_price: "21133000",
    sell_price: "21147000",
    date: "1513812135042"
  }
}`

So your code gets the 0th character of the `sell_price` string.  Try:

`var USDPrice = data.data.sell_price;`

Comment: Ok got it now, it may be because of a version error in my ftp or in my cache ! Thanks a lot !